# Ember #each content doesn't update when replacing model

Tags: ember.js

I have the following `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each todo in todos}}
      <li>{{todo}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <button {{action 'generate'}}/>Generate a to-do</buton>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And `app.js`:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {});                                                                                                                                                                               

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {todos: ['To-do 1', 'To-do 2']};
  },
});

// This is a function I cannot change, because I don't own it.
// So I'm forced to get the updated model as the result of this.
// Here is some dummy-but-working implementation, for simulation purpose:
function generate(todolist) {
  var n = todolist.todos.length + 1;
  todolist.todos.push("To-do " + n);
  return todolist;
}

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    generate: function() {
      var oldToDoList = this.get('model');
      var newToDoList = generate(oldToDoList);
      this.set('model', newToDoList);
      console.log(this.get('model').todos);
    },
  },
});
```

When I click on the *generate* button, I effectively see the growing to-dos array in console, but UI doesn't update.

Shouldn't `#each` content update automatically when completely replacing controller's model, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your generate method doesn't actually generate a new array, so Ember won't notice that you've changed the property (because it's a reference to the same array).  In your particular instance you should just use `pushObject` and Ember will know you're modifying the same array.

```
function generate(todolist) {
  var n = todolist.todos.length + 1;
  todolist.todos.pushObject("To-do " + n);
  return todolist;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the Ember API in the `generate` function, because it would add an overkill dependency to the lib it belongs to. But your first reference-related answer pointed me to the right direction. It was probably not working because some object or array was not cloned properly. Thank you very much :)